# Create Mockito test for class with non default constructor and dependency injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection, constructor, mockito

I have a class that makes use of dependency injection and has a non default constructor that initializes additional fields. Basically the class looks something like this:

```
public class NonDefaultConstructor {
    private final String name;
    @Inject
    private SomeService service;

    public NonDefaultConstructor(ParameterObject po) {
        this.name = po.getName();
    }
}
```

With this `ParameterObject`:

```
public class ParameterObject {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I want to create a Mockito test that injects a mock of the service `SomeService` and a mock of the constructor argument `ParameterObject`. This attempt does not work, as it tries to mock behaviour on fields that are not yet initialized.

```
public NonDefaultConstructorTest {
    @Mock
    private SomeService service;
    @Mock
    private ParameterObject po;
    @InjectMocks
    private NonDefaultConstructor classUnderTest;

    @BeforeEach
    private void setup() {
        given(po.getName()).willReturn("name")
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Creating the `ParameterObject` in the `setup` method does not work either, as that would require to construct `NonDefaultConstructor` there as well and then the `SomeService` would not be injected.
I am aware that this can be solved by using reflection to inject the fields manually, but I would prefer a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your `ParameterObject` "by hand" in your setup method like this:

```
@BeforeEach
private void setup() {
    po = Mockito.mock(ParameterObject.class);
    given(po.getName()).willReturn("name");

    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

In order to make this work, you also need to remove the `@Mock` annotation from

```
@Mock
private ParameterObject po;
```

Now, your `ParameterObject` gets created and configured before any other mock is created and then injected into your class with non default constructor.

Comment: Now that MockitoAnnotations.initMocks() is deprecated, I wonder if there is non-deprecated way to do this?